# Execute VB Script from VC++ & pass parameters to VB Script?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to Execute VB Script from VC++ and pass parameters to that VB Script & Read it ?
Currently I am using ShellExecute to Execute that VB Script but now i want to pass parameters to that VB Script and read it . How i can achieve that ?

My code looks like this : ChangeDrive.vbs is VB Script

```
HINSTANCE hInst = ShellExecute(0,                           
                                       "open",                      
                                       "ChangeDrive.vbs",               
                                       NULL,                
                                       0,                           
                                       SW_SHOW);
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

Adding VBScript and JScript support in your C++ applications
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/scriptdemo.aspx